# How to configure and where to put a servlet in NetBeans 7.4 accepting parameters from a .jsp page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans

I have previously worked with `Tomcat` but don't know how to configure and where to put a `servlet` which I want to accept parameters from a `.jsp` page for further processing. Indicating the actual file system path in the "action" tag results in `"resource not available"` or `"not found"`. How should I configure the `servlet` including the "action" element in the `.jsp`, the `web.xml` and the file system? Thank you.

Comment: Do you wanna know how to map your servlets to receive requests and send responses from/to your jsp pages?

Answer (score 0):

A JSP is a servlet too, and hence you could immediately **forward** to the servlet. *(Normally it is the other way round, the servlet as Controller, preparing a Data Model as request attribute and forwarding to a JSP View for displaying the data.)*

The servlet could be defined in the web.xml with a servlet mapping. If you use annotations instead the mapping is similar.

```
<%
request.setAttribute("answer", "42");
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/myservlet");   
rd.forward(request, response);
return; // No output from the JSP
%>
```

In the above "/myservlet" would correspond to the servlet mapping.
Forwarding does not go back to the browser, but leaves that to the servlet forwarded to.

You may alternatively **redirect** to the servlet. That means going back to the browser that then calls the servlet's URL.

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(redirect));
```

Though looking more circumstantial, it is frequently used to prevent the user navigating back on a posted form, submitting the form twice.

If your question relates to file paths. `request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/css/styles.css")` is the normal way to receive file system paths.

In NetBeans one makes a Web-Project generating a .war to deploy, and servlets may reside in any package you like. WEB-INF/web.xml for the traditional minded, Annotations in the servlet class otherwise.